# can we use Google Photos as Image Picker in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-photos

My designer came up with this design

[image]

i've tried to use library `image_picker` & `file_picker` but looks like it doesn't satisfy my needs so far

let's say i create the bottomsheet at image above,
so how do i programmatically use Google Photos as Image Picker? tthanks